# Не знаю как подключить расширение php-mysqli в докере

Tags: php, mysql, docker, apache

Я хочу сконфигурировать себе лабораторию для изучения уязвимостей баз данных. По статье с античата решил сделать сборку php+apache+mysql. Запускаю все это в докере. Вот так написаны конфиги докера:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: lab
      MYSQL_USER: aoizora
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

В папке src рядом с конфигами я разместил php-скрипт:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "aoizora", "123")
        or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
    print ("Connected successfully");
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Но при обращении к этому скрипту по адресу `http://localhost:8080/db.php` я получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

Оказалось, что надо установить расширение php-mysqli, но я не знаю, как это сделать. Я добавил такие строки в Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

Но это не помогло. Как правильно в моих конфигах подключить нужное расширение php?

Comment: RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli и устанавливает расширение. может быть надо пересоздать контейнер? Мне другое интересно, что еще за такие уязвимости баз данных?

Comment: SQL инъекции https://forum.antichat.club/threads/195037/

Comment: бог ты мой, какие страсти. "Представим, что дверь сейфа открыта. Сейчас мы покажем вам, сколькими способами можно переложить деньги из сейфа в сумку"

Comment: вам в пхп конфиге надо еще включить

Comment: @teran  в смысле? А кто ошибку тогда выдает, если не включен?